# How to Print data in django view file?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i am Selecting data using djano query.i am using following query

```
def myfunction(request):
     mydata=MyModel.objects.all() #this is query
    return HttpResponse (mydata) # i am using this for printing data
```

its showing me result in below formet,

```
MyModel object(28) MyModel object(29) MyModel object(30)
```

i want to print the data which is inside the object.How to do that?

Comment: try mydata.values()

Comment: share your template code

Comment: its working. thank you  Eric Martin.

Answer (score 0):

try `mydata.values()`

see explanations here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values